# Linq: Produce one result from two linq sources

Tags: linq, concatenation

I have two linq statements which both prouce an output of the same tye. How do can I merge this two linqstatements into, so that I get a single list.

Example:

```
var list1 = new List<string>() {"hello", "world", "!"};
var list2 = new List<string>() {"hello 2", "world 2", "! 2"};

var linq1 = from item in list1
            where item.Contains('o')
            select item;
var linq2 = from item in list2
            where item.Contains('l')
            select item;

var joined = linq1.Concat(linq2);
```

Output:

```
[0]: "hello"
[1]: "world"
[2]: "hello 2"
[3]: "world 2"
```

I want to have this in a single linq statement.

Comment: If you want a `List` object, `var list = joined.ToList();`

Comment: Do you want to "merge"(`Union`) both or do do you concat both? In the former case you have to override `GetHashCode`+`Equals` or provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use `Concat` as you have. But instead of `linq.Concat(linq2)`, you just put the queries there:

```
var joined = list1.Where (w => w.Contains("o"))
                  .Concat(list2.Where (w => w.Contains("l")));
```

Concat doesnt have a query syntax equivalent. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386979(v=vs.110).aspx)

So you'd do something like this:

```
var joined = (from item in list1
            where item.Contains('o')
            select item)
              .Concat(from item in list2
            where item.Contains('l')
            select item);
```

Comment: Can i get this into a single linq statement with from item in ...., because I really like this syntax :)